# Custom query in elasticsearch with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am new at elasticsearch and I'm trying to make a custom query with ElasticSearchRepository.
Input Data :

```
List<Long> bookId;
Long authorId;
Timestamp from;
Timestamp to;
```

How could i find a number of books with **List bookId**, check that all of them has the same **authorId** and check that they were published between timestamp **from** ... **to** ...  ?

For example i think that it could look like

```
List<Books> findAllBooks (List<Long> booksId, Long authorId, Timestomp from, TimeStamp to);
```

I use spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoolQueryBuilder and NativeSearchQuery Api helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you must create your query and add the @query annotation.
Something like this:

```
@Query("{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"range":{"field_date":{"gte":"from","lte":"to"}}}],"must":[{"term":{"authorId":{"value":"authorId"}}},{"terms":{"bookId":"booksId"}}]}}}")
List<Books> findAllBooks (@Param("booksId") List<Long> booksId, @Param("authorId") Long authorId, @Param("from") Timestomp from, @Param("to") TimeStamp to)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but, I learn how to work with BoolQueryBuilder and NativeSearchQuery Api and it help's me.